# How to customize aspxgridviewpager?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview, custom-server-controls

Currently i wish to use wcf get the data and bind it into aspxgridview but the  DataServiceConfiguration  had set the paged query----> config.SetEntitySetPageSize("*", 10);
so every time i will only get maximum 10 records only. isn't possible to customize the aspxgridviewpager so that it know the total record in database and only retrieve the current page record from wcf? example : i have  100000 records i had set config.SetEntitySetPageSize("*", 10);
when i bind to aspxgridview, the gridview will display it has 10000pages and retrieve the current page record only which is 10 records only. i had tried to use wcfservermodesource but it will not show data when config.SetEntitySetPageSize("*", 10); had be setted... so i change to customize the aspxgridviewpager.... Isn't possible to do it?  thx...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevExpress recommended way to achieve this is implementing `IListServer` interface. 
WCF implementation is [WcfServerModeSource](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressDataWcfLinqWcfServerModeSourcetopic). There is an [example](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/K18557.aspx) built for Windows Forms but you should be able to apply it to ASP.NET also. I'm a bit confused because of class location (`DevExpress.Xpf.Core`). However, you should contact DevExpress support in order to clear if ASP.NET support `WcfServerModeSource`.

Also, take a look at:

- [IListServer / ServerMode overview - WPF docs - should apply to ASP.NET as well](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6279)
- [Server side data management](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3726) - seems to me that this article lacks info about 
  [EntityServerModeSource](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressDataLinqEntityServerModeSourcetopic) and [WcfServerModeSource](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressDataWcfLinqWcfServerModeSourcetopic).
- [A possible implementation of IListServer interface to achieve Server Mode functionality](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E166.aspx)
- [LINQ server mode](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument4059)
- [Tickets regarding WCF and IListServer in DevEx support](http://search.devexpress.com/?q=IListServer+WCF&p=T4%7cP5%7c0).

If you choose to implement this functionality without `IListServer`, you could loose a big part of `ASPxGridView` functionality.

Comment: Actually i had tried on WcfServerModeSource it work fine without SetEntitySetPageSize("", 10);.But if SetEntitySetPageSize("", 10); the the aspxgridview will show nth.....

Comment: Did you try to set page size using SettingsPager.PageSize ASpxGridView parameter?

Comment: i set 5 row for a page but it also show nth but it will show total page count

Comment: What do you mean by "show nth"? Grid doesn't show first page or you have n rows in a page?

Comment: You wanted it to show 5 rows in page? As for blank, you probably have some problem with binding data to grid columns.

Comment: yes, and the DataServiceConfiguration had setted SetEntitySetPageSize("", 10);  so i will load 2 pages... i'm sure that is no problem on the columns.. if i remove the SetEntitySetPageSize("", 10);   then everything is alright.

Comment: Why do you need SetEntitySetPageSize if WcfServerModeSource handles paging?

Comment: Thats not mine decision.... because scare of the webserver down when other ppl direct query all the records...

Comment: Yes, but that way ASPxgridView doesn't get all data needed to correctly handle grid paging. You should choose between available options. Or try opening ticket in DevEx support and see if they have some other idea.

Comment: What do you mean by "available options"? Is there any other options?

Comment: Option 1: Remove SetEntitySetPageSize, Option 2: First answer you received. I don't know if this can be solved with option 2. I advice you to remove SetEntitySetPageSize or try with DevEx support.